# Apache Commons Configuration: Duplicate entries with enabled auto save

Tags: java, configuration, apache-commons-config

I use a `org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration` containing two `org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration` instances. One is used as default configuration and is deployed with my JAR the other one is the user configuration that can overwrite the default values.

Here is some code that loads the instances:

```
    XMLConfiguration defaultConfig = new XMLConfiguration(defaultConfigFileURL);
    XMLConfiguration userConfig = new XMLConfiguration(extConfigFilePath);
    userConfig.setAutoSave(AUTO_SAVE);
    FileChangedReloadingStrategy strategy = new FileChangedReloadingStrategy();
    strategy.setRefreshDelay(FILE_REFRESH_RATE);
    userConfig.setReloadingStrategy(strategy);
    userConfig.setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());
    defaultConfig.setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());
    this.config = new CombinedConfiguration();
    this.config.setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());
    OverrideCombiner oc = new OverrideCombiner();
    this.config.setNodeCombiner(oc);
    this.config.setThrowExceptionOnMissing(true);
    this.config.addConfiguration(userConfig, "USER");
    this.config.addConfiguration(defaultConfig, "DEFAULT");
```

With `AUTO_SAVE = true` the `userConfig` instance automatically saves changes to the file which is working so far. My problem is, that it adds the paramters multiple times so the config file looks chaotic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<fst_configuration>
<parameters>
        <WS_PASS_TO_SAP>true</WS_PASS_TO_SAP>
<PATH_CESA_DIR>C:\FST-RELEASE\FST\build\web\WEB-INF\cesa</PATH_CESA_DIR>
<PATH_ERIC_WORK_DIR>C:\FST-RELEASE\FST\build\web\WEB-INF\eric</PATH_ERIC_WORK_DIR>
<PATH_HSQL_DB>C:\FST-RELEASE\FST\build\web\WEB-INF\db</PATH_HSQL_DB>
<PATH_HSQL_DB>C:\FST-RELEASE\FST\build\web\WEB-INF\db</PATH_HSQL_DB>
<CESA_CMD_VERSION>17566520</CESA_CMD_VERSION>
<PATH_HSQL_DB>C:\FST-RELEASE\FST\build\web\WEB-INF\db</PATH_HSQL_DB>
<CESA_CMD_VERSION>17566520</CESA_CMD_VERSION>
</parameters>
(...)
```

For example, I change the parameter `PATH_HSQL_DB` at startup. After 3 startups the paramter is stored 3 times in the file assigned to `userConfig`.

This is the code that adds a paramter to the `userConfig` instance:

```
(...) // value is a String
String name = "PATH_HSQL_DB";
String keyString = String.format("/parameters/%s", name);
userConfig.addProperty(keyString, value);
```

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Could you add the code which inserts the PATH_HSQL_DB Key/Value?

Comment: I added the code above...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue now.

Comment: Turns out my issue was different ([this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION-560) if anyone else has a similar problem).

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a property rather than setting one. Use

```
String name = "PATH_HSQL_DB";
String keyString = String.format("/parameters/%s", name);
userConfig.setProperty(keyString, value);
```

Adding a property doesn't remove existing ones, setting them does.

- [addProperty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/AbstractConfiguration.html#addProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)
- [setProperty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/AbstractConfiguration.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)